# get list of ontologies in Virtuoso with their properties and classes

Tags: c#, ontology, virtuoso, dotnetrdf

Is there any place (such as an object like `VDS.RDF.Ontology`) that holds the list of ontologies (with their properties and classes) which are integrated in an instance of OpenLink Virtuoso?

I program in `C#` (I use `dotNetRDF`) and I hesitate to use a query to get this information.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

In the RDF universe, an ontology is just another graph; each graph should be self-describing; and each ontology graph should therefore include a statement that basically says "I'm an ontology."

Presuming such best practices have been followed, you can use a [query like this](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&qtxt=PREFIX%20%20owl%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20rdf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fontology%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fontology%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20owl%3AOntology%20%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fontology&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000) to get a [list of ontology named graphs](http://linkeddata.uriburner.com/sparql/?default-graph-uri=&query=PREFIX%20%20owl%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F07%2Fowl%23%3E%20%0D%0APREFIX%20%20rdf%3A%20%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2F02%2F22-rdf-syntax-ns%23%3E%20%0D%0A%0D%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Fontology%0D%0AWHERE%20%7B%20%3Fontology%20%20rdf%3Atype%20%20owl%3AOntology%20%7D%0D%0AORDER%20BY%20%3Fontology&should-sponge=&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000000) that are described behind a given endpoint --

```
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?ontology
WHERE { ?ontology  rdf:type  owl:Ontology }
ORDER BY ?ontology
```

Note however that it is not necessary for an Ontology graph to be loaded into Virtuoso (or other quad/triple/RDF store) in order for that ontology's terms to be used in other graphs loaded into that store, so I wonder at the purpose of your question...

ETA: Given that you have a list of named graphs for the ontologies in a given instance, you can get their content with queries like this --

```
SELECT * 
FROM <http://purl.org/vocab/relationship/>
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
```

-- which you can execute through an ADO.NET connection from C#, through the Virtuoso ADO.NET Provider, by turning it into SPARQL-in-SQL a/k/a SPASQL with the simple prepending of the SPARQL keyword and appending of a semicolon --

```
SPARQL
SELECT * 
FROM <http://purl.org/vocab/relationship/>
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o } ;
```

It may now go without saying, but to be clear -- you can also issue the initially described query as SPASQL via ADO.NET --

```
SPARQL
PREFIX  owl:  <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX  rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?ontology
WHERE { ?ontology  rdf:type  owl:Ontology }
ORDER BY ?ontology ;
```

*(ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of [Virtuoso](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/).)*

Comment: First, thanks for your replay. But I knew the queries which get these information. What I need is something else like this:   https://github.com/dotnetrdf/dotnetrdf/wiki/Ontology-API  But in place of reading and saving Graph by file, I'd like to initialize it by Virtuoso.

Comment: As I'm programmer in objet oriented languages, I prefer to use the objects (like objects in dotNetRDF specially OntologyGraph)  to do the queries. That's my motivation to asking this question here.

Comment: I've added a bit to my answer, which may provide what you're looking for.